# Ember JSONSerializer conditional embedding

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Is it possible to have conditional embedding in `JSONSerializer`? In my app I have some model relationships I don't wish to include on some pages.

For example:

**video detail page**
`this.store.query('video', {filter: {include: 'tags'}})`, here the `tags` should be embedded

**search results page**
`this.store.query('video')`, here tags should NOT be embedded.

Defining:

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        tags: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
});
```

will always embed `tags` into any `video` model, and so calling `this.store.query('video')` will throw an error because the `tags` attribute will not be present in the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `attrs` attribute in the serializer on the fly, so you can set `embedded` if you detect that tags are embedded -

```
attrs:
    tags: {}

normalizeResponse: (store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) ->
    if <hash has tags embedded>
        @attrs.tags.embedded = 'always'
    @_super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType)
```